# How to sign app for AppStore in my customer's name

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

If I'm developing an iPhone app for CompanyX and when we want to put it on the App Store using CompanyX's signature, and if they dont have the source code, can they do it themselves?

Or do I have to do it with their signature, since I have the source code and then submit it to the App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have settled on a process where "CompanyX" gives us an account to their iTunes connect so we can build, sign and upload to the App Store in their name.

Probably you can build it on your machine, send them the product and they sign and upload it themselves, however that would  be more tedious, as Apple's toolchain with Xcode and the Organizer has become quite good at this for the "usual" case of someone uploading their "own" apps.

Comment: tnx can you also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859398/apple-store-acceptance-submitting-an-app-which-users-other-services-for-profit

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to sign the source code with the key you get from Apple to submit it.