# Releasing an App for a client

Tags: ios, certificate, release, distribution

So I have just finished building an iOS app for a client and they want me to release it under their company developer account.

I am an admin for the account but not an agent.

I cant build the app for release because i don't have the Distribution certificate and key pair and they arn't smart enough to do it themselves.

How can i release this app to the app store?

ALSO: i have been over eery possible reference i could find so far but no one seems to have the answer.

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859398/apple-store-acceptance-submitting-an-app-which-users-other-services-for-profit/6866907#6866907 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856777/how-to-sign-app-for-appstore-in-my-customers-name/6856888#6856888

Answer (score 0):

For creating Provisional profile follow this step:

1)go to : developer.apple.com
2)then go to : member center and login 
3)after login : iOS Provisioning Portal
4)and star with "Launch Assistant" and follow ahed steps are mention in new window are open.